# Micronaut's HttpClient: connection pool, connection-pool-idle-timeout and connect-ttl: how do they work in conjunction?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I'm in doubt about the settings below:

- micronaut.http.client.connect-ttl
- micronaut.http.client.connection-pool-idle-timeout

I would like to understand:

- What is the purpose of the settings below?
- How do they differ?
- How do they work together?
- Are these settings useful if the pool is DISABLED (micronaut.http.client.pool.enabled = false)?

The micronaut documentation is not clear to me.